# AWS load balancer does not trigger latency-based descaling if no data is received

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently testing out doing some auto-scaling within AWS Elastic Beanstalk, trying to get very small EC2 instances to fire up and then remove themselves on a short time-scale. I've played with different triggers and the one that seems to make most sense is latency, or at least the CPU utilisation just didn't work quickly enough.

I've found that getting them to be created works fairly well assuming a spike isn't insanely large, but they don't want to go down unless there's *some* latency of some sort recorded which is below the bottom threshold. But having no traffic leaves all of them switched on.

Here are my settings:

[image: Auto scaling settings]

And here's my instances list. You can see there are 8 sitting there dormant but because there's no latency data, it does nothing:

[image: Dormant instances]

Is there any way to get it to include no latency data as meaning it can scale down? Or do I need to just use something with continuous data like CPU? (Which as I've said I've had issues with)

Thanks

Comment: I think you're going to have to use a continuous metric, or if you must use latency based then automate the scaling yourself with lambda calling the EC2 APIs.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I think I solved it by going into the load balancer itself in EC2 and setting latency to add instances and low CPU to lower them. I can answer it myself with that or close the question, or wait to see if someone else has any other ideas!

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't think of that, I work more in the networking / policy area of AWS. I think you should answer your question, it's a good solution :)